# How to find top 5 spenders for a certain year?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables: `Orders` and `OrderDetails`. The Orders table contains information about customer orders, including an OrderID (primary key), CustomerID, and OrderDate. The OrderDetails table contains details about the products in each order, including an OrderDetailID (primary key), OrderID (foreign key to Orders), ProductID, Quantity, and UnitPrice.

How can i write a single quary to find the top 5 customers (CustomerID) who have spent the most money on orders (sum of Quantity * UnitPrice) within the year 2022.

So far I have used this:

```
SELECT 
    O.CustomerID,
    SUM(OD.Quantity * OD.UnitPrice) AS TotalSpent
FROM
    Orders AS O
JOIN
    OrderDetails AS OD ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
WHERE
    YEAR(O.OrderDate) = 2022
ORDER BY
    TotalSpent DESC
LIMIT
    5;
```

Comment: You need to `group by` for aggregate function. `group by O.CustomerID`; That's my guess you haven't really described what happens with this code...I presume you get back 1 row with everything aggregated into it.